# Streaming multiple batches of data between two python scripts using pipe operator

Tags: python, python-2.7, pipe, stdout, stdin

I would like to continuously stream data from `script1.py` to `script2.py` without creating intermediate files on disk. An example of what I am trying to do is the following:

`script1.py`

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(5):
    print i # stream of data
    print 'eof' # marker to separate files 
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The output of this script does exactly what I want. 0-4 are printed with one second sleep period.

I would like `script2.py` to collect data from `script1.py` until the string 'eof', write it to stdout immediately and wait for the next batch of data.

`script2.py`

```
import time
import sys
data= sys.stdin.read()
sys.stdout.write(data)
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(1)
```

When I try to run:

```
python script1.py | python script2.py
```

`script2.py` waits for the entire data from `script1.py` (0-4) and then writes them to stdout together instead of one number at a time. Is it possible to stdout data from `script2.py` after a `stdout.flush` from `script1.py`?

UPDATE Based on Comment:

I cannot call `script2.py` from `script1.py` because both the scripts are located in different docker containers and I would like to avoid installing docker inside a docker container.

Comment: You can bypass the shell by calling script1 from script2.

Comment: @James Is it possible to do this from shell? The reason is because script1 and script2 are located in different docker containers. Sorry to not include this in the question. I will update it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read only one line at a time with `readline` in `script2.py`:

```
import time
import sys
while True:
    data = sys.stdin.readline()
    sys.stdout.write(data)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Version that prints only the numbers whenever it it sees `eof`:

```
import time
import sys

data = ''
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line.strip() != 'eof':
        data += line
        continue
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(data)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
        data = ''
```